# How to show different messages in a POV display?

Tags: arduino

I picked up a Propeller Clock (POV Clock) code from YouTube and modified to only display 2 messages: "Hello" and "World".

I want the POV display to show "Hello" for 2 seconds and then "World" for other 2 seconds but I'm having problems with that.

At the moment the code only shows "Hello" very fast and after 2 seconds it shows it again.

I know I need to keep the LEDs blinking for 2 seconds showing the word, erase and show the other word, but I don't know how to do it.

If someone can help me I will appreciate it.

- I'm using a Pro Trinket 5V 16 MHz
- Source of the original code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMfcs0iO8zE&t=43s

```
const int LEDpins[] = {
  4,9,10,11,12,8,6,5
};
int rows= 8;
const int charHeight = 8;
const int charWidth = 5;
const unsigned char font[95][5] = {};
const int sensorPIN = 3;
int sensVal;
int i;
int j;
int conteo = 0;
char textString[] = "Hello";
char textString01[] = "World";
String tmp_str;

void setup() {
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    pinMode(LEDpins[i], OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  Print();
  delay(2000);
  Print01();
  delay(2000);
}

void Print() {
  tmp_str=tmp_str+" ";
  while(digitalRead(sensorPIN) != 0) {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  for (int k=sizeof(textString)-1; k>-1; k--){
    printLetterboven(textString[k]);
  }
}

void Print01() {
  tmp_str=tmp_str+" ";
  while(digitalRead(sensorPIN) != 0) {
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  }
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  for (int k=sizeof(textString01)-1; k>-1; k--){
    printLetterboven(textString01[k]);
  }
}

void printLetterboven(char ch) {
  if (ch < 32 || ch > 126){
    ch = 32;
  }
  ch -= 32;
  for (int i=charWidth-1; i>-1; i--) {
    byte b = font[ch][i];
    for (int j=0; j<charHeight; j++) {
      digitalWrite(LEDpins[j], bitRead(b,j));
    }
    delay(1);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    digitalWrite(LEDpins[i] , LOW);
  delay(1);
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to "Accept" my answer by clicking the gray check icon when you get a chance, so that others may benefit from your question, and from my answer, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`millis()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis), which returns the time since the sketch started in milliseconds.

```
unsigned long t1 = millis(); // Get the time at the start
unsigned long t2;

void loop()
{
    t2 = millis()            // Get the current time

    if(t2-t1 < 2000){        // Runs until 2 seconds have elapsed
        Print();
    }
    else if(t2-t1 < 4000){   // Runs after 2 seconds have elapsed, until 4 seconds
        Print01();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is fine if you want to print each text once and once only.  To repeat your message in a loop, you need to reset the start time after both words are printed, something like:

```
unsigned long tStart;
unsigned long tNow;
unsigned long duration;

void setup()
{
    tStart = millis();
}

void loop()
{
    tNow = millis();
    duration = tNow - tStart;

    if(duration < 2000) Print();
    if(duration >=2000 && duration < 4000) Print01();
    if(duration >=4000)
    {
        tStart = millis();
        tNow = tStart;
    }
}
```